# How to type combinePromise function in typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-typings

I have this existing JS function, which is an alternative interface to `Promise.all()`. Is there a way to type it with TS?

```
// Like Promise.all() but taking an object<key,promise<?>> and returning object<key,promiseValue>
export const combinePromises = obj => {
   const keys = Object.keys(obj);
   const values = Object.values(obj);
   return Promise.all(values).then(results => {
      const combinedResult = {};
      results.forEach((result, i) => {
         const key = keys[i];
         combinedResult[key] = result;
      });
      return combinedResult;
   });
};
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
const {user,company} = await combinePromises({
    user: fetchUser(), 
    company: fetchCompany()
});
```

Given the fetch functions are typed, I expect the response (user and company) to be typed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `combinePromises` must return a Promise since `Promise.all` returns a Promise.

```
function combinePromises(obj): Promise<...>
```

Now, what needs to go into `...`? Well, you want the result to be basically the same object that's passed in, but with the values resolved.

#### Enforcing the same keys

To force the returned value to have the same keys as the passed in value, you need to make use of generics and the [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) operator:

```
type MyType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ... };
function combinePromises<T>(obj: T): Promise<MyType<T>>
```

Now, after you `await` the result of `combinePromises`, you will have an object whose keys are the same keys of the passed-in object.

#### Enforcing similar values

The second part is a little trickier since you can't unwrap Promises to fetch the inner types. You can, however, define a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) that infers the type of what's supplied to `Promise<...>`:

```
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : any;
```

The definition means, if the type `T` that's supplied to `ThenArg<...>` can be assigned to `Promise<infer U>`, then return type `U`. Otherwise, default to type `any`.

So `ThenArg<Promise<User>>` will return `User`.

Your final type definition and function signature should look like this:

```
type MyType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ThenArg<T[K]> }; // T[K] is the Promise value of the object passed in
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : any;

function combinePromises<T>(obj: T): Promise<MyType<T>>
```

And the `combinedResult` declaration should look like:

```
const combinedResult: MyType<T> = {} as MyType<T>;
```

Same type of object just without the Promise layer since inside of `Promise.all`'s `then`, they're already resolved.

---

The full solution will look something like this:

```
async function fetchUser(): Promise<User> {
    return new User();
}
async function fetchCompany(): Promise<Company> {
    return new Company();
}

class User { name:string }
class Company { }

type MyType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ThenArg<T[K]> };
type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : any;

export const combinePromises = function combinePromises<T>(obj: T): Promise<MyType<T>> {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    return Promise.all(values).then((results) => {
        const combinedResult: MyType<T> = {} as MyType<T>;
        results.forEach((result, i) => {
            const key = keys[i];
            combinedResult[key] = result;
        });
        return combinedResult;
    });
};

(async () => {
    const { user, company } = await combinePromises({
        user: fetchUser(),
        company: fetchCompany()
    });
    user.name; // we can access user.name since that's a member of User
})();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll have to read more carefully to understand how your solution is built but at least it solves me problem :)

Comment: Hey, just read about a Deferred type in TS. Do you think your solution could be rewritten with Deferred? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: @SebastienLorber I don't see how. The only time a key needs to be mapped to a promise is for the parameter passed in to the function, and we use `T` for that. The other types we added (return type and `combinedResult`) use the unwrapped Promise type as the value type, not the actual promise. Maybe I misunderstand what you're asking me to rewrite.

Comment: I don't exactly know yet what I'm doing, just asking if you see another possible solution with a provided MappedType ;) if you don't I'll be fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just did:

```
const [ user, company ] = await Promise.all([
  fetchUser(),
  fetchCompany()
]);
```

and got the right types.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-combine-promise-typed

Edit:

This is not a good answer because it doesn't directly answer the OP question. But it could be beneficial to others knowing you can use `Promise.all` this way.  and maybe the OP could consider using `Promise.all` directly.

Comment: OP isn't using Promise.all directly. He's calling a wrapper function that returns an object, so this won't work.

Comment: If all he is doing with the object that returns is destructuring it then what is the point of the wrapper function. (when you can destructure the result from Promise.all and have typeing)

Comment: I'll still upvote this answer because with a typed language my interface is less useful and Promise.all is typed. Yet, I actually want to return an object of the shape `{user, company}` in the end so my interface still makes me win some line of code/readability